# How to duplicate rows using another data grid in Pentaho 8 CE

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a data grid with the following fields and one row:

```
Data Grid
Fields: A   , B   , C
Row 1:  fooA, fooB,
```

I have another data grid with the following rows -just one field-:

```
Intervals
Fields: C
Row 1:  10
Row 2:  20
Row 3:  35
Row 4:  40
```

I would like to understand which Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) step/box shall be used to get:

```
Fields: A   , B   , C
Row 1:  fooA, fooB, 10
Row 2:  fooA, fooB, 20
Row 3:  fooA, fooB, 35
Row 4:  fooA, fooB, 40
```

[image: Merge two data grids]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a simple Join Rows (Cartesian product), though i do not know how exactly are you going to use this for variable data, if the Grid with 1 row multiple columns will ALWAYS have 1 row and multiple columns than it is fine, a cartesian product will replicate fooA, fooB in N' rows from the second grid.

All you have to do first in the second grid is split the single field into 2 columns, one with the "Row X" and another with the number value.

Your KTR should look something like this:

[image]

Which outputs this:

[image]

Comment: Actually the split step is not needed, as I need just `fooA,fooB,10` etc.